# Выскакивает ошибка при деплое телеграмм бота на Хероку

Tags: python, telebot, heroku

Пытался задеплоить на Хероку бота согласно гайдам.При делое выдает ошибку билда,в requiments.txt записаны все используемые библиотеки,все сделал как было написано,делал это через Github.
Тот самый Github: https://github.com/Bubunduc/Aiki-telegram-bot-without-token
Вот, что выводит консоль:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaBzI.jpg

Comment: Что в консоли пишет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Деплоинг не совершался потому, что я совершил ошибку в названии файла requirements.txt